# What is an unbiased electrical search stimulus?

Tags: pain, neurology

The following is an excerpt from Wall and Melzack's Textbook of Pain, sixth edition:

"When an **unbiased electrical search stimulus** is used, however, the prevalence of type I and type II A-fiber nociceptors in the hairy skin of the primate is similar."

What is an unbiased electrical search stimulus?

Comment: Not my field so I'm not posting an answer as I'm not sure if this is it, but can this help: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3330779/ look for the third passage in discussion.